# VBA - inserting a variable number of columns in a specific location in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I need help inserting a variable number of columns into a table using VBA. What I have so far is:

```
Private Sub copy_data(filename As String)
    disable_updates

    If Not filename = "False" Then
        Set dest_workbook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set src_workbook = Workbooks.Open(filename, True, True)

        test = copy_sheet_with_links(src_workbook.Worksheets("Main"), dest_workbook.Worksheets("Reference"), 0, 0)
        test = copy_sheet_with_links(src_workbook.Worksheets("PMP"), dest_workbook.Worksheets("PMP"), 1, 1)

        src_workbook.Close False
        Set src_workbook = Nothing

        dest_workbook.RefreshAll
        dest_workbook.Worksheets("PMP").Select
    End If

    enable_updates
End Sub
```

The number of columns to be inserted is in cell `B19` on the "Reference" worksheet. The columns are to be inserted in a table called `PMPTable` on the "PMP" worksheet.

Comment: what happens in the `copy_sheet_with_links` sub?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention where about in your PMP sheet want to add the new columns... however, assuming that is starting at column C, i would do something like this:

Assign the number of the columns to a variable

```
Dim nrCols As Long
nrCols = dest_workbook.Sheets("Reference").Range("B19").Value
```

Resize the range starting at column C with the `nrCols` value, and insert the columns.

```
With src_workbook.Sheets("PMP")
    .Range("C:C").Resize(, nrCols).EntireColumn.Insert
End With
```